# Create custom field on post draft or publish?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

How to automatically create custom field on post draft or publish with one of several offered values?
For example I wish to create custom field named "random_color" with one of potential values: "white", "green", "blue"...

Any of values is acceptable, so how to create function which will create post custom field with one of values (randomly chosen from defined) on post draft or publish?

I found this, it is working, it creates "random_color" custom field on post draft with value "blue". How to make it randomly chose one of other values like, white, green?

```
add_action('draft_post', 'add_custom_field');
function add_custom_field($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'random_color', 'blue', true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is pure PHP logic, which is off-topic here. Ask better in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an array and [choose one for the value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

```
add_action('draft_post', 'add_custom_field');
function add_custom_field($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {

        $colors = array('white', 'green', 'blue');

        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'random_color', $colors[array_rand($colors, 1)], true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It creates custom field 'random_color' but with "1" as value instead one of "white", "green" or "blue" as value.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code with the working code.

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_transition_post_status()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_transition_post_status/) is catch–all function for status changes. You can use one of the hooks inside (`transition_post_status` or dynamic ones) to target specific status conditions and run code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @rarst but I will need more help.